# const param vs non-const param

Tags: c, assembly, constants

Let's take the following two function:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void my_print1(char* str) {
    // str = "OK!";
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

void my_print2(char* const str) {
    // str = "OK!";
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

They both produce the [`same assembly`](https://godbolt.org/z/bKaa6P):

[image]

How then is the `const`-ness enforced here? For example, if I un-comment `str = "OK!;` it will of course work in the first function call but not the second (`error: assignment of read-only parameter ‘str’`).

Is the `const`-ness of a local variable just a compiler construct, and it is responsible for checking that, or how does it work if the assembly for the two functions is the same? Note: this is C only, not C++ (as I think they treat const different).

Comment: As you say, it's a compiler construct, it does the checking before creating the assembly. It's compile time, not run time.

Comment: @David542 The question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `const` qualifier on function parameters and other local variables normally has no effect on the generated code. It just tells the compiler to prevent assigning to the variable.

Theoretically, it could generate code that prevents modifying the variable through other means. E.g. if you had

```
void my_print2(char* const str) {
    *(char *)&str = "OK!";
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

The assignment causes undefined behavior, but won't cause an error (although the compiler might warn about casting away constness). But the compiler could theoretically store `str` in memory that's marked read-only; in that case, the assignment would cause a segmentation fault. This would not normally be done for function parameters because it's difficult to reconcile that with using the stack for automatic data. (Nate Eldredge's answer explains this better.)

Answer (score 4):

Correct, on most implementations it's just a compiler construct.

On a typical mainstream OS implementation, there is a way to place `const` objects having `static` storage duration in memory that is actually write-protected by the CPU's memory-management unit (MMU), e.g. a `.text` or `.rodata` section.  Then attempts to write it, if not prevented at compile time, will cause a trap at runtime.  But hardware write protection applies to large blocks of memory (e.g. whole pages).  There is no good way to do this with `auto` objects, such as local variables or function parameters, which live in stack memory or in registers.  On the stack, since they are mixed in with non-`const` variables, hardware write protection is not fine-grained enough to apply to them, and in any case would be very expensive to be continually changing (it needs a call to the operating system).  And registers on most machines cannot be made read-only at all.

Since there is no good way to protect them at runtime, compilers often generate the exact same code for `const` auto objects as for non-`const`.

You might see differences in some cases, since `const` informs the compiler that the object's value is not *supposed* to change, and therefore the compiler can assume that it does not.  For instance, if you pass a pointer to a non-`const` object to another function, the compiler has to assume that the value of the object may have been changed, and will reload it from memory after each function call.  But a `const` object may have its value cached in a register across the functionn call, or just optimized into an immediate constant if possible.

Comment: `it's just a compiler construct` NO. It is the language construct. Not the compiler. The actual implementation does not matter. `const` correctness is something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler enforces `const` by refusing to generate non-compliant code. If the `my_print2` source had attempted to modify `str`, the compiler would have issued an error message.

With respect to your code however:

`void my_print2(char* const str)...`

It's kind of pointless as it can only limit what the function can do with the value of the pointer itself, not what it can do to memory it points to, so:

```
void my_print2(char* const str)
{
    str++; // Not allowed, compile time error.
    *str = 'A'; // Okay.
}
```

Functions that do not need to modify the content of what is pointed to, should be declared as `const <type> *` to give callers confidence that your function, print in this case, won't change their data:

```
void my_print3(const char* str)
{
    str++; // Okay
    *str = 'A'; // Not allowed, compile time error.
}

void my_print4(char const* str)
{
    str++; // Okay
    *str = 'A'; // Not allowed, compile time error.
}
```

Comment: I get an error on both, for `str++;` --> `increment of read-only parameter ‘str’` and for `str = 'a';` `assignment of read-only parameter ‘str’` and for `*str='A';` it's a seg fault.

Comment: @David542, I deliberately left out the compiler error output because they can vary by compiler and even across compiler versions.

Comment: `str = 'a'` should fail for `char *str` because of a type mismatch.  `*str = 'A'` will compile for `char *str`.  Calling it with `my_print("foo")` compiles because C lets string literals implicitly convert from `const char*` to `char *`, but that does *not* make it safe to write into string literals.  They do have static storage duration and are in `.rodata` like Nate explained.  Look at the asm.  Passing a pointer to read-only memory to a function that wants a non-const pointer is your problem, and exactly what `const char *str` would save you from, as this answer explains.

Comment: @PeterCordes, it's not `str = 'a'`, it's `*str = 'a'`.

Comment: That statement does appear in David's comment, separate from `*str = 'A';`.  IDK what he's talking about, but it's in there separate from from claim of getting a segfault.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Ah, I get your point now, apologies.  I was deliberately avoiding the implementation details. I thought the OP's question had more to do with "Is the const-ness of a local variable just a compiler construct, and it is responsible for checking that,...". Full coverage of this subject is a book chapter level task.

Comment: @jwdonahue: The Stack Overflow question was what you thought.  Only the comment on your answer introduced additional wrinkles, including C UB by passing a string literal to a non-const `char *` that actually does get modified.  C allows string literal -> `char*` for historical reasons: const didn't exist in early C so even read-only functions like `strlen` took a `char*` not `const char*`.  But anyway, your answer is fine, the OP just managed to confuse themselves with other things while trying to understand it I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227923/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-peter-cordes).